# Отправка email не учитывает настройки в env

Tags: laravel

При отправке почты пишет:

> (1/1) Swift_TransportException
>
> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "study@lsweb.ru" using 1 possible authenticators

Хотя в `env` другие настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас эти данные захардкоджены в файле `config/mail.php`
для того чтобы данные  laravel брал с env измените параметры массива на следующие:

```
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
```

P.S. ну и другие по аналогии.